# why condition $id dont work with pagination?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

i have two models binded with section model this two models called (gallery,article),i want to paginate all this in sections/view.ctp.so i have two problems
**1-when put $id in $paginate to retrieve articles by section $id i get parse error**
                  **2-how to separate between the two paginations (gallery,article) in view file ..**

```
var $paginate = array(
     'Article'=>array(
     'limit' => 1,
     'page' => 1,
           parse error here//  
     'conditions' => array('section_id'=>$id)
     ),
     'Gallery'=>array(
     'limit' => 3,
     'page' => 1,
     'conditions' => array('section_id'=>86))


     )
     ;
    function view($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid gallery', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
   $gallery = $this->paginate('Gallery');
        // find Articles at sections
         $articles = $this->paginate('Article');
   $section = $this->Section->findById($id);

        // set the section for the view
    $this->set(compact('articles','gallery','section'));
    }
```

sections/view

```
    <div class="related">
        <table>

            <tbody>
<h3> section is <?php echo $section ['Section']['name']; ?></h3>
<br />
                <?php foreach($articles as $article): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php if($article['Article']['status']== 1){echo $article['Article']['title'];}  ?></td>
                    <td><?php  if($article['Article']['status']== 1){echo '&nbsp;'.$html->link('View', '/articles/view/'.$article['Article']['id']);}?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>



        <?php if($section['Section']['id']==86): ?>
        <div class="related">

        <table>

            <tbody>

                <?php foreach($gallery as $galler): ?>
                <tr>
                 <td> <?php echo '&nbsp;'.$html->link($galler['Gallery']['name'], '/galleries/view/'.$galler['Gallery']['id']);?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <p>
    <?php
    echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
    'format' => __('Page %page% of %pages%, showing %current% records out of %count% total, starting on record %start%, ending on %end%', true)
    ));
    ?>  </p>

    <div class="paging">
        <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('<< ' . __('previous', true), array(), null, array('class'=>'disabled'));?>
     |  <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers();?>
 |
        <?php echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next', true) . ' >>', array(), null, array('class' => 'disabled'));?>
    </div>
     <?php endif ; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use variables or logic in class property declarations in PHP. For one, there's no scope for that `$id` variable up there anyway.

To pass conditions to the pagination query, you need to add it as a second argument to your `paginate()` call:

```
$articles = $this->paginate('Article', array('Article.section_id' => $id));
```

You will struggle to get two instances of pagination working on the same page, as CakePHP will not know which set of data you are paginating when it received "page:2" in the URL, and I think it will just paginate both sets of data. [Here is an article outline a possible hack](http://debuggable.com/posts/how-to-have-multiple-paginated-widgets-on-the-same-page-with-cakephp:48ad241e-b018-4532-a748-0ec74834cda3).